# Unable to observe node (update not receiving) in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat listing with react native and firebase. My firebase database is like this.

[image]

[image]

I am able to list the chats but it is not updating when a new chat adds or when I send a new message in old chat. My code is like this.
// find chat tread ids for a user.

```
firebase.database().ref('user/64/threads')
  .on('value').then(snapshot => {
    // find chat thread details for a id
    const chatIds = snapshot.val();
    for (let chatId of chatIds.keys()) {

      firebase.database().ref('threads/'+chatId).once('value')
      .then(snapshot1 => {
        // find members from snapshot.val().members
        // find id of other users.
        if (chatId.split('-')[0] == '64') {
          // find name of chatId.split('-')[1]
        } else {
          // find name of chatId.split('-')[0]
        }
      })
    }

  });
```

I am stuck in this forever. I am able to fetch chat listing one time but I am not getting whenever a new chat is added or when a new message is added in existing chat. Please help.

Comment: are you using firebase javascript or rnfirebase.io

Comment: I am using third party npm named "firebase" of version "5.4.1",

Comment: try this https://rnfirebase.io. It can be issue of the library.

Comment: I can not change the library in middle of the project. Can you help with this one.

Comment: ok, how are you updating your component in react after data change ?

Comment: I am unable to fetch data changes, after fetching data first time I am using setState to update state of view. The problem is I am not receiving callback on data changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182331/discussion-between-vishu-bhardwaj-and-umar-hussain).

Comment: What's your chat ref you are looking for ? user/64/threads or threads/ ?